# Where to find Spark SQL syntax reference?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Do we know any syntax reference for `spark-sql`? I mean the style like [MySQL SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), or [PostgreSQL Documentation: SELECT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html).

If not, what is the best source we can access?

Comment: After *much* searching, I found this question. I do not agree that it is off topic, the question is tagged apache-spark and apache-spark-sql, and I don't think it is unreasonable to request help in finding the documentation for those. I can attest this is not a trivial quest.

Comment: I found good documentation from databricks. Here is the documentation for `SELECT` in latest version of spark-sql: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/select.html

Comment: Here is some unofficial documentation that helped me: https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/index.html

Comment: This is finally coming in Spark 3.0. You can see a preview of the documentation here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview2/sql-ref-syntax.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

SparkSql follows Hive style, so you can refer to Hive Syntax for better [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select).

The supported and unsupported Hive features by SparkSql can be found in the official [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive).

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html

Comment: Official documentation link above, as well as comment by JasonWayne do not connect to the requested information. The spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html documentation doesn't even list `SELECT`.

Comment: There now is this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax.html

Answer (score 4):

> If not, what is the best source we can access?

I don't know about any better source that could be considered *"the best"* but the source code of Apache Spark itself. I can imagine that is not as user-friendly as the mentioned sources, but Apache Spark is a highly dynamic open source project and it'd be very hard to keep up with all the changes.

If you're asking about what's supported in so-called SQL mode, you should consult [SqlBase.g4](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4) which is the ANTLR grammar of Spark SQL. Unless there's a bug in ANTLR you cannot do anything but what's in the grammar.

Comment: Postgres is a dynamic open source project with the best documention I have ever seen. Is it 'highly dynamic'? Not sure.