# How to delete duplicate rows

Tags: sql, duplicates

Some rows share same primary keys(ID) but the rest of the row maybe different. For example

```
ID   Age   Info
2    21    2763
2    21    6276
3    31    82756
```

In this case, both the first and second rows has same ID and Age, but different Info. What I want do with duplicate ID rows is to randomly keep one of them and delete the others. I have so many this kind of records in my Data Sets so I can not delete them one by one. Is there any solutions? Thanks

Comment: which is your primary key in this table?

Comment: @Adish PK is ID in this example. Thanks

Comment: How can a PK allow duplicate values? Anyway, you want to remove duplicate IDs, right? or is it a combination of ID and Age that has to be treated as duplicate?

Comment: @Adish Remove duplicate IDs is good enough for my case Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I'm using SQL Thanks

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos No. Actually I'm using Apache Spark, but it allow me to use SQL command lines to modify table

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos So I have a SQL Context Table and I can modify it with SQL lines just like in MySQL

Comment: You need to tag this Apache Spark, not SQL even if you're using Spark SQL.  There is *no* universal method for deleting duplicates from a table with SQL because ANSI SQL says you should design your table such that it's impossible to insert duplicates.  As a result, the way you have to do this will vary wildly between RDBMSs.  Spark SQL appears to use a [very small subset of SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887571/spark-sql-syntax-reference).  I would doubt if any solution would work that you'd get here.

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks for your response. I will update my question!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE t1
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.Age = t2.Age AND t1.Info > t2.Info
```

The above should work in MySQL, SQL Server. The statement deletes all rows in a `(ID, Age)` slice *but* the one having the smallest `Info` value.

**Note:** The above works provided that `Info` values are unique per `(ID, Age)` slice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  What are t1 and t2?

Comment: @GavinNiu They are table aliases

Comment: This will not delete rows where IDs match but Age does not. This will not delete rows where all three columns are identical.

Answer (score 1):

With window function:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by info) rn 
             from table)
delete from cte where rn <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
delete from TableName where info not in 
(select min(info) from TableName group by ID,Age);
```

try the select statement first to make sure it's returning the right rows then add the delete part to it

Comment: Let me try! Thanks for your response!

Comment: This will only work if `info` is unique.  A row of ID = 2, Info = 82756 would throw it off.

Comment: Correct, the assumption per the example is that Info is unique per grouped ID and Age.

Comment: For this query to work `Info` must be unique on table level

Comment: Yes, it works with the example, but in my real case info is not unique. I apologize that I gave a bad example..

Comment: @SergioSain  So instead of deleting the min Info, how can I just randomly delete one of those duplicate? Thanks!

Comment: @GavinNiu So you want to *randomly* delete *just one* of the duplicates, delete *all* of the duplicates *but* the one having the minimum *info*, or what ?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Random delete one of the duplicates. So after delete I want  all rows' ID are unique Thanks

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: switch the Info field for the ID field in that statement and the ID field for the Info field...test it first with a select though just in case

Comment: So what you are saying is that you want one row per ID since the other fields can be duplicated across other rows, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested a set based solution, but I could not get to take care of rows in which all 3 rows are identical. Therefore suggesting a solution that uses ROWCOUNT and a while loop. The ROWCOUNT will ensure that only 1 record is deleted at a time. The while loop is so that you don't have to do it manually one by one.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1

DECLARE @ctr INT
SELECT TOP 1 @ctr = COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
SELECT @ctr
WHILE @ctr > 1
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    SELECT @ctr = NULL
    SELECT TOP 1 @ctr = COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
If @Ctr IS NULL
    Break
ELSE
    Continue
END
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

You can alter the order by clause in the delete statement to suit your requirement.