# What are the semantics of using a having clause on a window function in spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, having, having-clause

I am learning spark sql and noticed that this is possible:

```
SELECT   a, b, 
         Row_number() OVER (partition BY a, b ORDER BY start_time DESC ) AS r ,
         Count(*) OVER (partition BY a, b)                       AS count
FROM     tbl 
WHERE    ...  
**HAVING r <= 10**
```

As far as I know, having clause is something that can be applied only to an aggregation in a group-by clause. Impala does not recognise this syntax, nor is it documented in the only [reference I was able to find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887571/spark-sql-syntax-reference#) for spark sql.

What's up with that? Are the semantics the same as putting the same condition in a where clause in an outer query (like I normally would?)

Comment: what's your issue exactly? yes, you can use `where` after a window function.

Comment: @mtoto The question is what is the source of this syntax and is it equivalent?

Comment: you are not grouping so cannot use `having` if that's what you mean.

Comment: @mtoto, oh but I can and I did. To be more precise- I encountered this code written by someone else and was very much surprised that it is actually working.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now resolved - see here https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/IMPALA-2215

However, it may not be updated for older versions.